# Lookup serial numbers in excel through SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

In my Excel sheet, like below there are three fields. I would like to connect to SQL Server (myserver) database (checkdb). Checkdb database has a table (checktable) that has two fields (Material and SerialNumber). With this connection I want to look up each SerialNumber and Meterial and write some text to check field in my Excel sheet with the macro ;

- if SerialNumber exist and its Material is the same as the material name
  in the Excel sheet, macro will write "ok" to check field
- if SerialNumber exist but its Material is different from the material name in Excel, macro will write the material name in database refer to serial that we are looking for
- if Serial does not exist, macro will write "nok" to check field

Thank you for your help;
Regards,

Before Running macro, my Excel Sheet;

```
Material SerialNumber Check
MTR5100 1 
MTR5100 2 
MTR4100 3 
MTR4100 4
```

Checktable in checkdb on sql-sever;

```
Material SerialNumber
MTR5100 1 
MTR5100 2 
MTR6100 3 
MTR4100 5
```

After running macro, In my Excel sheet check field will be look like
this;

```
Material SerialNumber Check
MTR5100  1   ok
MTR5100  2   ok
MTR4100  3   MTR6100
MTR7100  4   nok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ADO:

```
''Reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim scn As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sFullName As String

''Probably not the best way to get the name
''but useful for testing
sFullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" _
& sFullName _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

cn.Open scn

sSQL = "SELECT IIf(c.Material=t.Material,'ok', " _
    & "IIf(c.Material<>t.Material,c.Material,'nok')) " _
    & "FROM [Sheet1$] t " _
    & "LEFT JOIN [ODBC;Description=TEST;DRIVER=SQL Server;" _
    & "SERVER=Server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" _
    & "DATABASE=test].CheckTable c " _
    & "ON t.SerialNumber=c.SerialNumber "

rs.Open sSQL, cn

''Might be problems with order of entries
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

The above uses a connection string for SQL Express, you can get more strings from: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Connection between excel and server worked great. I can select from server and excel. But I think I missed the named-ranges in excel. I could not run the sSQL field in the code. I got the error "No value given for one or more required parameters. (ADO Error)" I add the code like this; "'Dim Material As Range
'Dim SerialNumber As Range
'Set Material = Range("A2:A5")
'Set SerialNumber = Range("B2:B5")

Comment: I am not sure I get what you are doing with these ranges in VBA, nor am I sure how familiar you are with ADO, but the way the sample code works on a table with headers Material and SerialNumber. If the sheet has a named range for the table, you can use that instead of [Sheet1$], for example [My Range] or MyRange, you can also refer to a range like so, [Sheet1$A1:C7]. If HDR=No in the connection string, you can use F1,F2,F3 .... Fn for headers.

Comment: thank you much Remou, I was wrong that I had changed the header in excel. It works great, thank you

Comment: How can I use "ActiveSheet" instead of Sheet1 and FROM [Sheet1$] ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You can store the name to a variable and use it as required : `sSheet = ActiveSheet.Name` : `FROM [" & sSheet & "$] t "` : `Worksheets(sSheet).Range` (or if you are very careful, just `Range("c2")` ) :  and so on.

Comment: Remou thank you much. When I try to connect sql server "SERVER=x.x.x.x;User Id=myuid;Password=mypassword" I qot error "ODBC connection to server failed". Am I missing sth important?

Comment: You do not seem to be including the database. It is best to get your connection strings from : http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: I think, I have problem with the connection strings. In this code there are two connection, OLEDB for excel and the other ODBC for SQL Server. Is it possible to write sql string (sSQL) separately from ODBC connection (DSNless)? And I also tried DSN from ODBC DataSources **strConnect = "DSN=DSNcheckdb"** : **sSQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [" & strConnect & "].CheckTable"** I could not run.

Comment: The easiest way to obtain this string is through Microsoft Access, do you have it and can you connect to your server with it?

Comment: And I have one more question. To lookup every row in Excel sheet through SQL Server takes two seconds per row. How can I lookup fast ? Is there any alternative for ODBC for SQLServer ? If it is possible how can I use OLEDB in replace of ODBC ?

Comment: I do not have Microsoft Access and have no experience before.

Comment: How about [ODBC;DSN=MyServer;uid=<User ID>;pwd=<Strong Password>;database=pubs] see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245587

Comment: I am still having no luck with OLEDB for in-line connection, but this works for me: "ODBC;FILEDSN=C:\DSN\SQL Test.dsn"

Comment: Doing this work with excel did not work well. So imported the excel sheet into database. How can I query with MSSMS and match these two tables ? Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be best to post this as a separate question, because it no longer involves Excel, just SQL Server.

Comment: I have posted as a new question **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215744/sql-select-matches**

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in an Excel centric fashion is to import the entire table into a sheet.  In EXcel 2010, you can do that with `Data -> From Other Sources -> SQL Server`.

Then, in the existing sheet, you add a column labelled `Material from DB`, and fill it with `vlookup`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$3:$C$5,2,FALSE)
```

Then in the 4th column, you can compare the material from the sheet with the material from the database like:

```
=IF(A3=B3,"ok","mismatch")
```

Comment: yes works fine, I have more than 50 workbooks and every workbook has a sheet with more than 5000 rows. DB has more than 100000 records. I use db as a pool. Is there a way to automate this lookup like macro?