# SQL Select Matches

Tags: sql-server, match

I have two tables, I would like to match these two tables. I tried with Excel but I did not work well because Excel sheet has more than 200.000 rows. I got answer for excel -[Lookup serial numbers in excel through SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112388/lookup-serial-numbers-in-excel-through-sql-server-database)- 
I am looking for an answer for matching these two tables with MSSMS.
Regards,

FirstTable

```
Material SerialNumber 
MTR5100 1 
MTR5100 2 
MTR4100 3 
MTR4100 4
```

Checktable

```
Material SerialNumber
MTR5100 1 
MTR5100 2 
MTR6100 3 
MTR4100 5
```

I would like to match FirstTable with CheckTable

*if SerialNumber exist and its Material is the same as the material name in the FirstTable, it will write "ok" to check field

*if SerialNumber exist but its Material is different from the material name in FirstTable, macro will write the material name in database refer to serial that we are looking for

*if Serial does not exist, it will write "nok" to check field

With sql query, I would like to get this result;

```
Material SerialNumber Check
MTR5100  1            ok
MTR5100  2            ok
MTR4100  3            MTR6100
MTR7100  4            nok
```

Comment: Please describe the schema - what do the tables look like? What criteria are you matching them on (Like column name on table A is like column person on table B?  By MSSMS do you mean these tables are part of Systems Management Server or something else?

Comment: I have added some explanation. This tables are any kind of table on SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what your looking for is fairly trivial SQL. I think you should take 30 minutes, and learn some SQL yourself... It's really not that hard. Check these tutorials out:

[SQL Tutorials](http://sqlzoo.net/)

Lastly, you'll need to import your excel files. Often, this involves saving them as comma separated text files, and then importing those into the database of your choice.